# Open ID 2 is ending

Tags: discussion, login, google-openid

I just got a message when signing into a site that Open ID 2 with Google is ending:

[OpenID 2.0 for Google Accounts is going away](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6135882?authuser=0)

Will this affect me signing into the network with my Google Account?